# How to input underscore charactor on emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm a WP7 newbie.I have a textbox on my windows phone app. I didn't see the underscore character. I have searched the web, but I didn't find the answer. How can enter the underscore character on Emulator? I

Comment: I think it is relate to the development because I need to enter the underscore for testing my code.

Comment: Try pushing page-down on the keyboard(when focused on the emulator). On the Phone 8 emulator, this allows you to use your physical keyboard. Otherwise, there usually is an underscore reached by some alt or caps key of some such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. Tap on textbox and onscreen keyboard appears
2. click on '123' button to enter into numeric mode
3. Press and hold the '-' symbol and the '_' (underscore) symbol appears

By the way, did you really mean 'underline' or 'underscore' !!

Comment: Thanks. It is underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use your PC's keyboard to enter the underscore?

In order to do this you must first hit the Pause|Break key after you click inside the text box and the you will be able to use the keyboard without a problem.